# Show the folder name instead of whole directory path on gitbash

Tags: git, git-bash

Is it possible to change setting in gitbash so that it will display only the folder name of the current directory instead of the whole directory path? I am using windows 10.

Instead of below

```
abc@DESKTOP-5AU7PAM MAUGW64 /d/Workspace/angular-workspace/my-app (master)
$
```

I want gitbash to only display the folder name

```
abc@DESKTOP-5AU7PAM MAUGW64 my-app (master)
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your .bashrc at ~/.bashrc by your favourite editor then change:

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\e[32m\]\w \[\e[91m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$ "
```

to

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\e[32m\]\W \[\e[91m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$ "
```

(change `\w` to `\W`).

But i think is difficult to know what directory your are working on.

Comment: I couldn't find .bashrc file in root location (C:\Users\USERNAME), should i create a new file and add the content?

Comment: from your git bash : does `ls ~/.bashrc` also indicate "no such file or directory" ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, it does :(

Comment: I found bash.bashrc file in C:\Program Files\Git\etc location but it doesn't have the above code to edit

Comment: Ok, you can create it then

Comment: Sorry, i think you use linux. For Windows's user you can create `.bashrc` file inside `~` folder. `~` is usually your `C:\Users\<your user name>` folder. Typing `echo ~` in the Git Bash terminal will tell you what that folder is.

content of `.bashrc` file in your case will be:

`parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\e[32m\]\W \[\e[91m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$ "
`